# Request Handler & JSON/AJAX causing layout for json to only be used for requests

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got a few sites I'm building in cakephp and they've all started exhibiting this issue after updating to the latest version of cakephp.

The correct layout is used about 90% of the time, however; when you make an ajax request there is about a 10% chance that for the next few minutes every page you load will be loaded without a layout. The view is loaded, but the layout is not and thus no css or js is loaded.

Deleting the files in the /tmp/cache/persistent sometimes seems to fix the issue as well as disabling the RequestHandler component (though this makes .json requests not work anymore, so it's not really a solution)

Is anyone else experiencing this issue and had any luck resolving it?

Comment: I'm kind of experienced this issue but in early version: 2.5.4.
Try to add `$this->disableCache();` in your AppController inside beforeFilter action. This will forced loading layout without Cache every time you load or reload a page.

Comment: I have tried that, and sadly does not seem to fix the issue... I've even tried just globing and unlinking everything in the /tmp/cache/persistent folder and it seems to make the issue happen less, but it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066365/cakephp-requesthandler-returns-rss-json-instead-of-html) it's related to parseExtensions method and the requirement for html to be in it for it to not use "accepts" header for figuring out which format to use instead of the extension.